# STL Implementation of reheapify

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl, heap

In a graph algorithm, I need to find the node with the smallest value.

In a step of the algorithm the value of this node or its neighbors can be decreased and a few of its neightbors can be removed dependent on their value.
Also, I don't want to search the whole graph for this node each time (although it is not so big (<1000 nodes)).

Therefore I looked at the STL library and found the heap structure which almost does what I want. I can insert and delete nodes very fast, but is there a method to update the heap fast when I only changed the value of one node without resorting the whole heap? I feel it would be a huge bottleneck in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the conceptual part:
If you use the heap insertion method with the element that decreased it's value as the starting point for insertion instead of starting at the back of the collection everything just works.

I haven't done that in C++ yet, but std::push_heap looks fine for that purpose.